# ghostscript to convert a ps file to pcl loosing tray settings

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, printer-control-language

I'm using the below command to convert ps to pcl but the pcl when printed doesn't have the tray settings anymore, is there anyway of retaining them?

"gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=ljet4  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sOutputFile="c:\t.pcl"  "c:\t.ps"

e.g. in ps file:-

%%EndPageSetup
<> setpagedevice statusdict begin 1 setpapertray end

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no, the PCL output devices don't carry forward any 'metadata', just the marking content.